# Suppress Jboss version details from HTTP error response

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

My jboss verson is Jboss EAP 6.3

When any kind of error response is sent back by Jboss, it adds up server information to the response. Following is a sample row response:

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
**Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1**
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2391
Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 09:30:46 GMT
Connection: close

JBoss Web/7.4.8.Final-redhat-4 - JBWEB000064: Error report

## JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 400 - org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of mybean.type from String value 'XYZ': value not one of declared Enum instance names
 at [Source: org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl$InputStreamWrapper@5e421c2b; line: 14, column: 26] (through reference chain: RequestArgs["request"])

**JBWEB000309: type** JBWEB000067: Status report

**JBWEB000068: message** org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of mybean.type from String value 'XYZ': value not one of declared Enum instance names
 at [Source: org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl$InputStreamWrapper@5e421c2b; line: 14, column: 26] (through reference chain: RequestArgs["request"])

**JBWEB000069: description** JBWEB000120: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

#### JBoss Web/7.4.8.Final-redhat-4

---

Here, the server version can be replaced to any costume name using "-Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.SERVER=MyServer" parameter while starting up the server.
But how to replace "JBoss Web/7.4.8.Final-redhat-4" specified in title & footer?

By creating custom error pages (for each error like error_400.html, error_500.html etc), this can be resolved but then, the actual error message that needs to be included dynamically has a challenge.

Is there any easy way to just suppress any jboss version related information from all responses sent using Jboss?

Answer (score 0):

For this issue you need to configure custom error pages at JBoss EAP level.

1. Create a custom ROOT App to provide the custom error page as follows :

   - set enable-welcome-root="false" in standalone-*.xml or domain.xml in then web subsystem.
   - Deploy a basic ROOT.war archive with a web.xml that includes the error page for all http errors.

When, enable-welcome-root="true", the pages are served for welcome-content folder present in EAP 6 and when you hit for example localhost:8080, what you can see is the index.html page which is present in welcome-folder. Now if you deploy custom ROOT.war, you will see the custom error page you supplied.